# Code won't separate into the appropriate list based on input from the category variable. Also, the code won't repeat if I input yes

Tags: python, input, while-loop, append

I am building a code to accept inputs and separate those inputs based on category type. When I input my expense, the expense always appends to the "bills" list. Further, when asked if want to add another expense, doesn't matter what I input, the program ends rather than continues to move through the while loop.

```
# Create a program that sorts expenses by category after accepting user input.
# Define the lists that the expenses will be separated into.
bills = []
fun = []
take_out = []

def items_list():
    """A function to input expenses and sort them by category."""
    print("Please add your expenses here.")
    name = input("Name: ")
    cost = input("Cost: ")
    category = input("Category: ")
    expense = f"{name}, {cost}, {category}"

    # Add a flag to indicate that the program is ready to accept expenses.
    add_items = True

    # Add a while to accept expenses
    while add_items:
        # Separate the expense based on the category they fall under.
        if category == str("Bill") or str("bill"):
            bills.append(expense)
        elif category == str("Fun") or str("fun"):
            fun.append(expense)
        elif category == str("Take Out") or str("take out"):
            take_out.append(expense)

        # Ask the user if they would like to add another item.
        repeat = input("Would you like to add another expense? (Yes/No): " )
        if repeat == "No" or "no":
            add_items = False

items_list()
print(bills)
print(fun)
print(take_out)
```

Comment: You should tag this question with the language you are using.

Comment: Looks like the issue is how you are doing multiple conditions in your if statements - `if repeat == "No" or "no":` is not correct.

Comment: Looks like `Python` to me. Please correct if I'm wrong.